# what's the advantage of integrating GIT LFS with artifactory

Tags: git, artifactory

I am trying to use artifactory in my current project. Artifactory's large binaries storage / management feature made me want to try artifactory. I came across one feature in artifactory guide in below link
http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Git+LFS+Repositories

and I didnt understand what exactly is the advantage of integrating artifactory with GIT LFS, if GIT alone can provide feature of storing large binaries. Can anyone help me understand the advantage of this feature please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding to @joran answer, please note that your statement "GIT alone can provide feature of storing large binaries" is wrong.
GIT LFS was invented because GIT alone is not doing a very good job in handeling large binaries. GIT is a source control system, that relies a lot on the fact that sources are text and versioned by content.

GIT LFS is a layer, that allows you to use familiar GIT commands while manipulating a storage, more suitable for binaries. ATM there are [4 known implementations](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/wiki/Implementations) of such a storage, out of which Artifactory is the only universal artifact repository. That means that if you need a repository for any other technology Artifactory supports, you can use a single tool rather than setting up and maintaining a whole zoo of tools for different repository types.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: thanks @JBaruch for the explanation

Comment: @JBaruch, I agree that we need some LFS for larger repos (the cited statement was from original question), but aside from poor performance, do you know if git has any restriction in file size?

Answer (score 1):

Git is not well suited for handling versioning of large files, mostly because when cloning and fetching such repo you will download each version of the file (often waste of time and space and the problem accumulates for each new version)

Comment: Why downvote, is it incorrect?

Comment: The information in your answer is correct, but it does not answer OP's question of why Artifactory is advantageous.